# Only 3000 messages are indexed by Messages.app [INTERNAL] Reason: No recorded reason

Tags: macos, messages

I would like to search *All* text messages but see only a small / recent fraction of them. Here is the message:

[image]

> More results will be shown once Messages finishes indexing.
>
> [INTERNAL] Reason: No recorded Reason.  Indexed 3000/28506 records. Version 21. Last
> Reindex Completion Date 2022-04-19 12:37:44 +0000

This lack of search capability severely limits my ability to utilize the historical content of the Messages.